# Get specific nested table cell using Ruby Watir

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm writing a Watir program to extract a specific number from a dynamically-generated table. The number is always in the second column of the fourth-to-last row in the table, but I'm getting the following error when trying to access the general table element:

> Watir::Table: located: false; {:id=>"tContenido", :tag_name=>"table"}

**Code**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
$log = Logger.new('logs\test.log')
$log.info("TEST")
$log.info browser.table(:id, 'tContenido')
```

**HTML Structure of the target page (1)**
[image: HTML Structure of the target page (1)]

**HTML Structure of the target page (2)**
[image: HTML Structure of the target page (2)]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you visit the page? I didn't see method `goto` like this: `browser.goto "www.google.com"`

Comment: that's not an error, just the output of the `Element#inspect`. What happens when you do `browser.table(:id, 'tContenido').exists?`

Comment: @fongfan999 yes of course, my bad. I'm doing other things in my code so i simplified it and forgot to include that line

Comment: @titusfortner it outputs true. I wrote 

puts browser.table(:id, 'tContenido').text

and i got the whole table, but i can't seem to access its internal elements, i keep getting a timeout error

Comment: Elements in Watir are lazy loaded so seeing "located: false" just means you haven't tried to do anything with the element yet that required it to be looked up. So finding the table element itself isn't the problem, just figuring out what you want inside the table element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the one you are looking for:

```
browser.table(id: 'tContenido').tr(class: 'tr_gris', index -1).td(index: 1).text
```

Alternately, if you are having problems with a table, you can just put everything into an array of Hashes:

```
browser.table(id: 'tContenido').hashes
```

Comment: The first line worked! However, the 'tr_gris' element in the particular example i posted was the first one, however the table is different each time and i need to access the last ocurrence of it. I tried

`puts browser.table(:id, 'tContenido').tr(:class, 'tr_gris').last.text`

but am getting a "undefined method" error

Comment: the `tr` method will give you a `TableRow` object, the `trs` method will give you a `TableRowCollection` object. You can only call `last` on a collection, and can only use `index` parameters on an element.

Comment: the following line

`puts browser.table(:id, 'tContenido').trs(:class, 'tr_gris').last.td(index: 1).text`

finally solved my problem, thank you so much! That collection/element explanation made perfect sense

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the need to iterate over a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following WATIR code

```
puts b.table(id: 'tContenido').trs[-4].tds[2].text
```

Comment: I get the following:

6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:657:in `element_call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:664:in `rescue in element_call': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TableDataCell: located: false; {:id=>"tContenido", :tag_name=>"table"} --> {:tag_name=>"tr", :index=>16} --> {:tag_name=>"td", :index=>2}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

However,

puts browser.table(:id, 'tContenido').tr(:class, 'tr_gris').text does get me a full line. Of coourse, its not the specific one I need...